# Read and rbind multiple csv files

Tags: r, csv, data-binding, merge, dataframe

I have a series of csv files (one per anum) with the same column headers and different number of rows. Originally I was reading them in and merging them like so;

```
setwd <- ("N:/Ring data by cruise/Shetland")
LengthHeight2013 <- read.csv("N:/Ring data by      cruise/Shetland/R_0113A_S2013_WD.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
LengthHeight2012 <- read.csv("N:/Ring data by cruise/Shetland/R_0212A_S2012_WD.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
LengthHeight2011 <- read.csv("N:/Ring data by cruise/Shetland/R_0211A_S2011_WOD.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
LengthHeight2010 <- read.csv("N:/Ring data by cruise/Shetland/R_0310A_S2010_WOD.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
LengthHeight2009 <- read.csv("N:/Ring data by cruise/Shetland/R_0309A_S2009_WOD.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)

LengthHeight <- merge(LengthHeight2013,LengthHeight2012,all=TRUE)
LengthHeight <- merge(LengthHeight,LengthHeight2011,all=TRUE)
LengthHeight <- merge(LengthHeight,LengthHeight2010,all=TRUE)
LengthHeight <- merge(LengthHeight,LengthHeight2009,all=TRUE)
```

I would like to know if there is a shorter/tidier way to do this, also considering that each time I run the script I might want to look at a different range of years.

I also found this bit of code by Tony Cookson which looks like it would do what I want, however the data frame it produces for me has only the correct headers but no data rows.

```
multmerge = function(mypath){
filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
datalist = lapply(filenames, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=T)})
Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y)}, datalist)

mymergeddata = multmerge("C://R//mergeme")
```

Comment: Do you really need merge? What about do.call(rbind, datalist)?

Comment: `sep=",",header=TRUE` is default for `read.csv()`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Find files (`list.files`) and read the files in a loop (`lapply`), then call (`do.call`) row bind (`rbind`) to put all files together by rows.

```
myMergedData <- 
  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(list.files(path = "N:/Ring data by cruise"), read.csv))
```

**Update:** There is a *vroom* package, [according to the manuals](https://vroom.r-lib.org/) it is much faster than *data.table::fread* and base *read.csv*. The syntax looks neat, too:

```
library(vroom)
myMergedData <- vroom(files)
```

Comment: i have a similar issue and use: 
zoneB = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(zoneB)) assign(zoneB[i], read.csv(zoneB[i])) and then ZB = lapply(zoneB, read_csv) %>% bind_rows() ....... but i am wonder is there a a way to exclude specific .csv files in the list?

Comment: What if I need to pass parameters to the function on lapply? E.g. instead of read.csv I would like to use read.table and set some options on it.

Comment: Hey zx8754 - Thank you for this! Is there a way to keep an id on each document that the folder has?

Comment: @MelaniaCB Certainly possible, please ask a new questions with reference to this post, and provide example input and expected outputs.

Answer (score 15):

If you're looking for speed, then try this:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2 or 1.9.3
ans = rbindlist(lapply(filenames, fread))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try it in a tidy way like this:

```
   files <- list.files('the path of you files', 
                        pattern = ".csv$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
    
   myMergedData <- read_csv(files) %>% bind_rows()
```

Comment: I don't think you need the "%>% bind_rows()".

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough rep to comment, but to answer Rafael Santos, you can use the code here to add params to the lapply in the answer above. [Using lapply and read.csv on multiple files (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441204/using-lapply-and-read-csv-on-multiple-files-in-r/15758789)