# Combining multiple csv files into one data frame using a loop

Tags: r, loops, csv

I have a set of 125 .csv files that I want to combine into one data frame and file. Each csv file is one column of the data frame I ultimately want. I also need to add the site names at the beginning of the new data frame. The final result should look like this (with the rows all lined up, a 2x4 table in this example):

| site | species 1 |
| --- | --- |
| cole | 2 |
| fillmore | 4 |

| species 2 | species 3 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |

I have gotten this far in the code:

```
# your text read in list of files
files<-list.files(path = 'C:\\Users\\rache\\...\\individual csv files\\test', pattern = ".csv")

#create dataframe with names of sampling points
data_cols <- read_csv("raw_abund_counts.csv")

bups_all<-as.data.frame(data_cols[,1])

#the loop is where ther are problems, all else works correctly.
# read in bup files and add to dataframe
bups_all <-for(i in 1:length(files)) {
  tmp<-read.csv(files[i])
  bups_all<-cbind(bups_all, tmp)
}
```

When my associate runs the loops, she said that it would sometimes drop a site from the model, resulting in one less than our expected total. However, when I try to run the loop the bups_all changes from a data frame with my list of sites, and becomes a value that is NULL. Running the code in the loop manually does indeed link up the site names and the first column of data as I expected.
Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can probably use these methods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23995384/read-and-rbind-multiple-csv-files but replace `rbind` with `cbind` or `bind_rows` with `bind_cols`. Note that a `for` loop in R always returns NULL so you never want to do `bups_all <-for(...) {...}`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried the top recommendation on that thread, but I still just ended up with a NULL object. summary states: Length  Class   Mode 
     0   NULL   NULL

Comment: Try ``bups_all <- do.call(cbind, lapply(files, function(file){ read.csv(file) }))``